# Centered Toolbar icon on xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

I need to create a toolbar with a centered icon in a xamarin forms project.

The icon is changeable during the navigation of a MasterDetailPage, so changing Toolbar.xaml on .droid does not do the trick and ToolbarItems can't be centered.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Can you add some of your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my own question with a custom render for NavigationPage.

overriding OnElementChanged I can do

```
string pageName = e.NewElement.CurrentPage.GetType().Name;  
SetCustomView(pageName);
```

changing the icon depending of the Detail page name.